# TypeScript can't manage to use dictionary interface

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm relatively new to TypeScript and it keeps complaining that variables has type "unknown", so I decided to create an interface to fix this problem. But I can't manage to find a solution that works. This is what I've come with so far:

the data I want to use comes from a json that looks like this data.json, this json is simplified alot:

```
{
"userName":"usernamedummy",
"projects":{
   "key1":{
      "projname":"dummyname0",
      "layers":{
         "keyinside1":{
            "layername":"dummylayername0",
    
         }
      }
   },
   "key2":{
      "projname":"dummyname",
      "layers":{
         "keyinside2":{
            "layername":"dummylayername"
         }
   }
}
}
```

my main component looks like this:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import data from './data.json';
export interface Project {
    [key: string]: {
        projname: string;
        layers: {
            [key: string]: {
                layername: string;
            };
        };
    };
}
@Component({
    selector: 'app-layers',
    templateUrl: './layers.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./layers.component.less'],
})
export class LayersComponent {
    layerListSource: Project;
    constructor() {
        this.layerListSource = data.projects;
    }
}
```

and does a *ngFor with another component like this:

```
  <li *ngFor="let project of layerListSource| keyvalue">
      <app-layer-dropdown [project]="project"></app-layer-dropdown>
  </li>
```

in the other component it looks like this:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Project } from '../layers.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-layer-dropdown',
    templateUrl: './layer-dropdown.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./layer-dropdown.component.less'],
})
export class LayerDropdownComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() project!: Project;
    open: boolean;
    constructor() {
        this.open = false;
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log(this.project)
    }
}
```

Having this creates this problem:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The KeyValuePipe transforms your list into key/value pairs, so you'll need to bind to the value:

```
<li *ngFor="let project of layerListSource| keyvalue">
      <app-layer-dropdown [project]="project.value"></app-layer-dropdown>
</li>
```

See https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe for reference.

[edit] also, in your layer component, you'll probably have to change the interface, because what you are binding there isn't the dict, it's the values of the dict:

```
export interface LayerDict {
    [key: string]: {
        layername: string;
    };
}
export interface Project {
    projname: string;
    layers: LayerDict;
}
export interface ProjectDict {
    [key: string]: Project ;
}

// LayersComponent 
layerListSource: ProjectDict;

// LayerDropdownComponent
@Input() project!: Project;
```